# How to change legend fontsize with matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, size, matplotlib, legend

Simple question here:  I'm trying to get the size of my legend using `matplotlib.pyplot` to be smaller (i.e., the text to be smaller). The code I'm using goes something like this:

```
plot.figure()
plot.scatter(k, sum_cf, color='black', label='Sum of Cause Fractions')
plot.scatter(k, data[:, 0],  color='b', label='Dis 1: cf = .6, var = .2')
plot.scatter(k, data[:, 1],  color='r',  label='Dis 2: cf = .2, var = .1')
plot.scatter(k, data[:, 2],  color='g', label='Dis 3: cf = .1, var = .01')
plot.legend(loc=2)
```

Comment: For an updated answer, 2021, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62669552/2612410

Answer (score 804, accepted):

You can set an individual font size for the legend by adjusting the `prop` keyword.

```
plot.legend(loc=2, prop={'size': 6})
```

This takes a dictionary of keywords corresponding to `matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties` properties. See the [documentation for legend](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend):

> Keyword arguments:
>
> ```
> prop: [ None | FontProperties | dict ]
>     A matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties instance. If prop is a 
>     dictionary, a new instance will be created with prop. If None, use
>     rc settings.
> ```

It is also possible, as of version [1.2.1](http://matplotlib.org/api/legend_api.html#matplotlib.legend.Legend), to use the keyword `fontsize`.

Answer (score 127):

using `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

**Method 1: specify the fontsize when calling legend (repetitive)**

```
plt.legend(fontsize=20) # using a size in points
plt.legend(fontsize="x-large") # using a named size
```

With this method you can set the fontsize for each legend at creation (allowing you to have multiple legends with different fontsizes). However, you will have to type everything manually each time you create a legend.

(Note: @Mathias711 listed the available named fontsizes in his answer)

**Method 2: specify the fontsize in rcParams (convenient)**

```
plt.rc('legend',fontsize=20) # using a size in points
plt.rc('legend',fontsize='medium') # using a named size
```

With this method you set the default legend fontsize, and all legends will automatically use that unless you specify otherwise using method 1. This means you can set your legend fontsize at the beginning of your code, and not worry about setting it for each individual legend.

If you use a named size e.g. `'medium'`, then the legend text will scale with the global `font.size` in `rcParams`. To change `font.size` use `plt.rc(font.size='medium')`

Comment: Just to inform Python beginners (like me): Method 1 only works after creating a plot (after a plot() line) and Method 2 only works before creating a plot. Thank you. I agree with @Scott Gigante, this should be the answer!

Answer (score 83):

This should do

```
import pylab as plot
params = {'legend.fontsize': 20,
          'legend.handlelength': 2}
plot.rcParams.update(params)
```

Then do the plot afterwards.

There are a ton of other rcParams, they can also be set in the matplotlibrc file.

Also presumably you can change it passing a `matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties` instance but this I don't know how to do.  --> see Yann's answer.

Answer (score 53):

There are also a few named [fontsizes](http://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text.set_size), apart from the size in points:

```
xx-small
x-small
small
medium
large
x-large
xx-large
```

Usage:

```
pyplot.legend(loc=2, fontsize = 'x-small')
```

Comment: For me giving fontsize in points did not work, but your suggestion to use named fontsizes did solve my problem.

Answer (score 46):

Now in 2021, with matplotlib 3.4.2 you can set your legend fonts with

```
plt.legend(title="My Title", fontsize=10, title_fontsize=15)
```

where `fontsize` is the font size of the items in legend and `title_fontsize` is the font size of the legend title. More information in [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html)

Answer (score 22):

There are multiple settings for adjusting the legend size. The two I find most useful are:

- labelspacing: which sets the spacing between label entries in multiples of the font size. For instance with a 10 point font, `legend(..., labelspacing=0.2)` will reduce the spacing between entries to 2 points. The default on my install is about 0.5.
- prop: which allows full control of the font size, etc. You can set an 8 point font using `legend(..., prop={'size':8})`. The default on my install is about 14 points.

In addition, the [legend documentation](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend) lists a number of other padding and spacing parameters including: `borderpad`, `handlelength`, `handletextpad`, `borderaxespad`, and `columnspacing`. These all follow the same form as labelspacing and area also in multiples of fontsize.

These values can also be set as the defaults for all figures using the [matplotlibrc file](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/customizing.html).

Answer (score 7):

On my install, FontProperties only changes the text size, but it's still too large and spaced out.  I found a parameter in `pyplot.rcParams`: `legend.labelspacing`, which I'm guessing is set to a fraction of the font size.  I've changed it with

```
pyplot.rcParams.update({'legend.labelspacing':0.25})
```

I'm not sure how to specify it to the pyplot.legend function - passing

```
prop={'labelspacing':0.25}
```

or

```
prop={'legend.labelspacing':0.25}
```

comes back with an error.

Answer (score 6):

```
plot.legend(loc = 'lower right', decimal_places = 2, fontsize = '11', title = 'Hey there', title_fontsize = '20')
```

Answer (score 3):

you can reduce the legend size setting:

```
plt.legend(labelspacing=y, handletextpad=x,fontsize)
```

> labelspacing is the vertical space between each label.
>
> handletextpad is the distance between the actual legend and your
> label.
>
> And fontsize is self-explanatory