# How to change matplotlib patches Font Size without using mpl.rc()

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to generate some graphs, I wanted to have a bigger font for the axis scale so I used :

`font = {'size'   : 22}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)`

This affected my Legends size as in the figure:
[image: figure]

Is there anyway to control the size of `mpatches.Patch()` text ?

Comment: Could this be of any help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125009/how-to-change-legend-size-with-matplotlib-pyplot

Comment: What exactly are you trying to control? It seems the label `Ideal` is in the legend. Do you only want to change the size of one of the legend labels? Please also add a [MCVE].

Comment: @tom the size of the patches in general

Comment: @errata I found a similar approach in the question you provided. 
write the answer as:` plot.legend(......,prop={'size':6})` so i can choose your answer, and thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mpatches.Patch()` has no fontsize, since it has no text associated with it.

- To control the **label's fontsize** you can use rcParams, like

  ```
  plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 22
  ```

  or directly control the size of the label

  ```
  ax.set_xlabel("some label", fontsize=22)
  ```
- To control the **legend's fontsize** you can use rcParams

  ```
  plt.rcParams["legend.fontsize"] = 22
  ```

  or directly specify the size in the legend

  ```
  ax.legend(fontsize=22)
  ```