# How do I change the size of the scatter markers in the legend?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, legend, scatter

I am basically plotting a scatter graph with matplotlib, however, I have varied each point by a radius.

When I use `plt.legend()` to show my legend, it looks like this......
[image]

Is there a command to reduce the size of the circle. I know this is probably a very trivial question, and I have tried searching it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution may depend on whether the markers in the legend should be scaled compared to the original size or whether a constant marker size independent on the original size is desired.

#### A. Scale the markers

You may use the `legend.markerscale` [rcParam](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

```
plt.rcParams["legend.markerscale"] = 0.3
```

or the `markerscale` argument to the legend.

```
plt.legend(markerscale=0.3)
```

From the [legend documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.legend):

> `markerscale` : None or int or float
>
> The relative size of legend markers compared with the originally drawn ones. Default is None which will take the value from the legend.markerscale rcParam.

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["legend.markerscale"] = 0.3

plt.scatter([.3,.5], [.3,.6], s=1000, label="label")
plt.scatter([.7,.4], [.3,.6], s=81, marker="^", label="label2")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that this will scale all markers simultaneously.

#### B. Set a constant marker size

In case you want a constant marker size in the legend, independent on the actual size of the scatter points, the solution is slightly more complicated. You may use the legend's `handler_map` to set the desired marker size to the legend handles.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerPathCollection

sc = plt.scatter([.3,.5], [.3,.6], s=1000, label="label")
plt.scatter([.7,.4], [.3,.6], s=[100,300], marker="^", label="label2")

marker_size = 36
def update_prop(handle, orig):
    handle.update_from(orig)
    handle.set_sizes([marker_size])

plt.legend(handler_map={type(sc): HandlerPathCollection(update_func=update_prop)})
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I updated the answer with a solution for a constant marker size in the legend.

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me:

```
# Legend
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
lgd = ax.legend(handles, labels, framealpha=1, ncol=1, 
            bbox_to_anchor=(1.02,1), loc=2, fontsize=8, borderaxespad=0.)

for legend_handle in lgd.legendHandles:
    legend_handle.set_sizes([50])
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125009/how-to-change-legend-size-with-matplotlib-pyplot)?

```
params = {'legend.linewidth': 2}
plot.rcParams.update(params)
```

Comment: `legend.linewidth` does not exist as rcParam.