# how to reduce the size of legend in this plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geospatial

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20,20))
ax = file[file['NAME'].isin(['Alaska','Hawaii']) == False].plot(ax=ax, color='#3B3C6E')
hurigeo.plot(column='Wind', marker="<",  markersize=10,edgecolor='0.8',cmap='Blues', legend=True ,ax=ax)
plt.legend()
ax.set_title("Hurricane Florence in US Map", fontsize=25)
```

[image]

Comment: Follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125009/how-to-change-legend-size-with-matplotlib-pyplot

Comment: You can simply use `plt.legend(fontsize=10)` or any other value than 10 as per your taste

Comment: do you mean the size of the colorbar rather than the legend?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Matplotlib colorbar size to match graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195758/set-matplotlib-colorbar-size-to-match-graph)

Comment: thank you all. I got the solution by reading documentation.