# categorical data not fitting text into plot legend from dataframe when using seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am using pandas in conjunction with numpy, matplotlib, seaborne and a load of data. I am plotting dataframe data with the following line of code

````
####MINIMIZED CODE#####
importing numpy ect

df=pd.read_csv("csvfile")
df["movieTitle"]=pd.Categorical(df["movieTitle"] #done for "movieTitle" 
df['releaseData']=pd.to_datetime(df["releaseData"]

df2=df.sort_values('inflationGross', ascending=True) ###which was disneyData2 in original code
df2=df=df2.head(100)

plot=rando=sns.lmplot(x='releaseDate', y='inflationGross', data=df2, fit_reg=False, hue='movieTitle', legend=True)
rando.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)


########ACTUAL CODE#########

rando=sns.lmplot(x='releaseDate', y='inflationGross', data=disneyData2, fit_reg=False, hue='movieTitle', legend=True)```
````

The plot itself is fine, however, the categorical data, which is a series of film titles won't fit entirely on the legend. There's a large number of categories, which I understand isn't good practice but I'd like to find a way to perhaps shrink text size, or format the legend correctly.
Everything has been imported correctly and I have checked there are no bugs in the code.
I would like to keep only using seaborne to analyse this data NOT matplotlib
Picture of the problem is included below.

[image: example of problem with legend]

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change legend size with matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125009/how-to-change-legend-size-with-matplotlib-pyplot)

Comment: Would you mind explaining what I'm missing? The only other line related to this plot is: **rando.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)** or the data preprocessing which is simply declaring that column 'movieTitle' is to be taken as categorical data. I simply would like to understand how to format the legend data.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating, I will edit this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly speaking, you can delete the automatically created legend and fetch the text of the original legend to create a new The legend will be set to (I set the font size to 8.) Since no data was presented, I modified the code on the official site for illustrative purposes. If the data is presented we will get some great answers from more people.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.set(color_codes=True)
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

g = sns.lmplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue='smoker', data=tips, legend=True, legend_out=True)

# Figure can hold multiple legends, so you can specify the first legend in the list
lg = g.fig.legends[0]
# Figure legend delete
g.fig.legends[0].remove()

# The list where the handle is kept
handles = lg.legendHandles
# Extracts only strings from the list of Text objects holding labels
labels = [t.get_text() for t in lg.texts]
print(handles)
print(labels)
g.fig.axes[0].legend(handles, labels, loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5), frameon=False, fontsize=8)
```

[image]