# How to change the font size of labels on a matplotlib plot (for text labels which is in plot figure)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, label, font-size

I want to change the font size of labels that were in the figure like:
[image]

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125009/how-to-change-legend-size-with-matplotlib-pyplot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change legend size with matplotlib.pyplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125009/how-to-change-legend-size-with-matplotlib-pyplot)

Comment: @Sujay I'm doing like `plt.plot(lr_fpr1, lr_tpr1, label="AUC= %0.3f (p<0.0001)" % lr_auc1, linewidth=4)` , could you please tell me where can I fit `plt.legend` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
plt.legend(["label1", "label2"], prop={"size":99})
```

Comment: Isn't that the same thing given in the link in the comments

Comment: it is the same thing