# "No artists with labels found to put in legend." error when changing the legend size in pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I want to make my legend size bigger in Pyplot. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39473158/7339624) to do that. Here is my code.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [15, 7]

lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,4,5,6]

plt.plot(lst)
plt.legend(fontsize="x-large") # Here I make it bigger but doesn't work
plt.legend(["This is my legend"])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

I get this warning and I don't know what is wrong. I don't understand what "Artist" means here.

> No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"Artist" is a term from matplotlib:

https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html

Presumably the error message means that there are no items in the legend whose font size can be changed.

Maybe pass the `fontsize` argument to the *same* `plt.legend` call in which you create the legend, or call `plt.legend(fontsize=...)` *after* you have created the legend.

Comment: `plt.legend(["This is my legend"], fontsize="x-large")` This worked.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is saying that legend was attempted to be created without any labels to show as a legend. The solution is to pass the label in the `legend()` call as the OP observed:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
lst = [1, 3, 2]

plt.plot(lst)
plt.legend(["This is my legend"], fontsize="x-large")
```

or pass the label in the `plot` call and draw the legend later.

```py
plt.plot(lst, label="This is my legend")  # <--- the label corresponds to this plot
plt.legend(fontsize="x-large")            # <--- the above plot's label is drawn in the legend
```